# C# Поиск bytes и замена 4 байт по Pos

Tags: c#

Использую данный код для замены 4 байт в файле (замена по позиции)

```
private void ChangePos()
        {
            try
            {
                string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Somefile.bin";
                string path2 = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Somefile2.bin";
                ReplaceDataCamera(path,
                                new int[] { 27421, 27425, 27429 },
                                new float[] { 55f, 56.54f, 86.43f });
                ReplaceDataCamera(path2,
                                new int[] { 27421, 27425, 27429 },
                                new float[] { 86.54f, 86.54f, 654.124f });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void ReplaceDataCamera(string path, int[] positions, float[] data)
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
                {
                    var tmpData = BitConverter.GetBytes((float)Math.Round((data[i]), 7));
                    stream.Position = positions[i];
                    stream.Write(tmpData, 0, tmpData.Length);
                }
            }
        }
```

У меня есть файл большого объёма, в нем надо менять 4 байта в определенных местах, файл периодически меняется, по этому меняется позиция но не меняется хекс.
Как мне приспособить данный код так чтобы я мог найти в файле bytearray допустим

F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 76 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CD CC 4C 3F 7D 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9A 99 59 3F

И поменять в нем 4 байта CD CC 4C 3F и 9A 99 59 3F?

Проще говоря, мне надо найти хекс значение и поменять в нем 4 байта без загрузки файла в память

Comment: `мне надо .. поменять в нем 4 байта без перезаписи файла` - это как?

Comment: Предлагаю использовать нашего знакомого компьютерного гномика.

Comment: @tym32167 не правильно выразился, не загружая весь файл в память

Comment: Читать побайтно и сравнивать конечно.. можно использовать матрицу значений, для увеличения скорости обработки, [например](http://perso.citi.insa-lyon.fr/trisset/cours/AGP/automate.c)..